# .unlist method will not work

Tags: excel, macos, vba, methods

This is probably a simple question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere on the net.  I am trying to unlist all the tables on a worksheet.  This macro fails with a message that says "Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found"  as it highlights the .Unlist part of the macro.  I have tried other variations but .Unlist does not seem to want to work.  I am on Excel for Mac 2011 (version 14.4)

```
Sub UnlistAllTablesOnSheet()
    Sheets("Role 1").Select
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oLo As ListObject
    Set oSh = ActiveSheet
    For Each oLo In oSh.ListObjects
        Application.Goto oLo.Range
        MsgBox "Table found: " & oLo.Name & ", " & oLo.Range.Address
         oSh.ListObjects(oLo.Name).Unlist
         MsgBox oLo.Name & "now unlisted"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Method to convert a ListObject to a Range is called `ConvertToRange` in Excel 2011.

Note that there are other issues in your code

1. use of `Select` and `ActiveSheet` is not required
2. nor is selecting the list object (`GoTo ...`)
3. once a listObject has been `UnList`ed, the variable `oLo` will no longer be set, so `MsgBox oLo.Name ...` will error

To make the code work on either PC or Mac, use Conditional Compilation

```
Sub UnlistAllTablesOnSheet()
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oLo As ListObject
    Dim nm As String
    Set oSh = Sheets("Role 1")
    For Each oLo In oSh.ListObjects
        MsgBox "Table found: " & oLo.Name & ", " & oLo.Range.Address
        nm = oLo.Name
        #If Mac Then
            oLo.ConvertToRange
        #Else
            oLo.Unlist
        #End If
        MsgBox nm & "now unlisted"
    Next
End Sub
```